# How can I select groups of rows from an Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have millions of data during the day in an Oracle table in three columns, Timestamp, Status and Value.

Select Rownum, Timestamp, Status, OrderId from temp_table rownum < 11; 
returns

1  2015-04-28T12:41:34.1616834Z Booking 100 
 
2  2015-04-28T12:41:34.1888649Z Delete  100 
 
**3  2015-04-28T12:55:59.3789387Z Execute 200 
 
4  2015-04-28T12:55:59.3825833Z Persist 200 
 
5  2015-04-28T12:55:59.3898336Z Book    200 
 
6  2015-04-28T12:55:59.3903645Z Delete  200** 
 
7  2015-04-28T12:57:37.5718992Z Booking 200 
8  2015-04-28T12:57:37.5723847Z Delete  200 
 
9  2015-04-28T12:57:37.5725199Z Booking 300 
 
10 2015-04-28T12:57:37.5728888Z Delete  300

I am interested in the list of four timestamps grouped by **Execute, Persist, Book and Delete** appearing together for every orderId for that day.

I am not interested in rows 7 and 8 even though the orderId is same [as  they are not grouped together by Execute, Persist, Book and Delete].

Can I do this by an analytic function?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag this with `plsql`? Do you want a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Do you want the first 4 timestamps for the day? And why is row 8 excluded - its status is "Delete"

Comment: I want all the Timestamps appearing in that ordered group set of Execute, Persist, Book and Delete for that day.

Comment: I think this can be done in PL/SQL but I would like to know if this is possible using analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but working query:

```
with t1 as (
  select tstamp ts, status st, orderid oid, 
      decode(status, 'Execute', 1, 'Persist', 2, 'Book', 3, 'Delete', 4, 5) ds
    from temp_table),
t2 as (
  select ts, st, oid, ds
    , decode(ds, 1, 1, lag(ds, ds-1) 
        over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)) d1
    , case when ds = 1 then lead(ds) over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)
           when ds = 2 then 2
           when ds = 3 then lag(ds) over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)
           when ds = 4 then lag(ds, 2) over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)
      end d2
    , case when ds = 1 then lead(ds, 2) over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)
           when ds = 2 then lead(ds) over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)
           when ds = 3 then 3
           when ds = 4 then lag(ds) over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)
      end d3
    , decode(ds, 4, 4, lead(ds, 4-ds) 
        over (partition by oid, trunc(ts) order by ts, ds)) d4
  from t1 )
select ts, st, oid from t2
  where (d1, d2, d3, d4) in ((1, 2, 3, 4))
  order by oid, ts, ds
```

Comment: Something is wrong with SQLFiddle.com site, anyway [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0370) is data I used.